# Unable to perform SQL request from CGI application(c++) - CGI hangs up on open database step

Tags: c++, html, apache

I've tested work of apache server with simple GET quest and worked
Then i've tested work of sql server with console c++ and it's worked.
To make them both work i've tried this code:

```
int main()
{
int nRetCode = 0;

HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);

if (hModule != nullptr)
{
    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, nullptr, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        wprintf(L"Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n");
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
        wprintf(L"Server: Apache\n");
        wprintf(L"Pragma: no-cache\n");
        wprintf(L"Cache-control: no-cache\n");
...
            CDatabase db;
            db.OpenEx(_T("Driver={SQL Server}; Server=..\\SQLSERVER;Database=...;Trusted_Connection=True;"));
            std::wstring str(_T("SELECT * FROM Play where  Play.NameOfThePlay='") + Name + _T("' or Play.NameOfThePlay like'") + Name + _T("%'"));
...
```

but it doesn't work!
Win32 application project exe was replaced with cgi - is it correct?